# Convert plotly marker from continuous to discrete

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Following is my input file i'm trying to display on a map using plotly.

```
data.csv
lat,long,type
-7.80715,110.371203,1
-7.791087,110.368346,3
-7.778744,110.365107,7
-7.77877,110.365379,4
```

The script works but the scale is displayed in a continuous format. I tried to convert the column `type` to text as mentioned [here](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/) but I couldn't get it to work. Is there a easier way to fix this problem?

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv").dropna()
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df["lat"].tolist(),
        lon=df["long"].tolist(),
        mode='markers',
        text=df['type'].tolist(),
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=10,
            color=df['type'],
            showscale=True
        ),
    ))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason, but you put `df[type]` instead of `df['type']`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a discrete color, you can either deal with it directly as a list of color specifications, or you can specify the default [color name](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express) in plotly_express.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

mapbox_access_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()
colors = px.colors.qualitative.D3

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df["lat"].tolist(),
        lon=df["long"].tolist(),
        mode='markers',
        text=df['type'].tolist(),
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=10,
            color=colors, 
            showscale=False
        ),
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    height=450,
    width=1000,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        style="outdoors",
        center=dict(
            lat=-7.78,
            lon=110.365
        ),
        zoom=10),
    showlegend = False
)

fig.show()
```

[image]